# OS Features API: Filtering by Intersects with Polygon

Tags: wfs, features, gml, ogc, ordnance-survey

I'm trying to use the [OS Features API](https://osdatahub.os.uk/docs/wfs/overview) to retrieve Greenspace within a Polygon. The OS example [here](https://labs.os.uk/public/os-data-hub-examples/os-features-api/wfs-example-intersects) demonstrates how this is supposedly possible, but when I try the same I cannot retrieve features.

I have tried the following request:

```
https://api.os.uk/features/v1/wfs
```

with the following query parameters:

```
service: wfs
version: 2.0.0
request: GetFeature
typeNames: Zoomstack_Greenspace
key: {{apiKey}}
outputFormat: GeoJSON
srsName: EPSG:27700
```

and with `filter` using a Box I can successfully perform the request. E.g:

```
<ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:Intersects>
      <PropertyName>SHAPE</PropertyName>
      <gml:Box xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:27700">
        <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=",">
          436833.50,115334.90,437643.25,115761.50
        </gml:coordinates>
      </gml:Box>
    </ogc:Intersects>
</ogc:Filter>
```

However with a Polygon instead of a Box:

```
<ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:Intersects>
      <PropertyName>SHAPE</PropertyName>
      <gml:Polygon xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:27700">
        <gml:coordinates>
          50.887107036372456,-2.154858 50.88639653297961,-2.1727248289496877 50.88427629228161,-2.1903082756046826 50.88077994091106,-2.207329528785897 50.87596292035441,-2.2235188409425026 50.86990159348424,-2.2386198651224105 50.86269201523514,-2.2523937627337745 50.854448388409246,-2.2646230132048037 50.84530123083424,-2.2751148627716202 50.83539528479962,-2.2837043569030944 50.824887203781635,-2.2902569090877254 50.81394305486918,-2.2946703676231017 50.80273567797704,-2.296876551419408 50.791441944852124,-2.2968422354151756 50.78023996203597,-2.2945695757801494 50.76930626235205,-2.2900959744428824 50.758813029162525,-2.2834933914533937 50.74892539662549,-2.27486712212967 50.73979886752439,-2.2643540637301953 50.731576887993434,-2.2521205034652243 50.72438861568274,-2.2383594659603663 50.718346914659264,-2.2232876637972807 50.71354660668353,-2.2071420994805577 50.71006300450259,-2.1901763711362343 50.70795074851218,-2.1726567374662666 50.70724296362755,-2.154858 50.70795074851218,-2.137059262533733 50.71006300450259,-2.1195396288637656 50.71354660668353,-2.102573900519442 50.718346914659264,-2.086428336202719 50.72438861568274,-2.0713565340396336 50.731576887993434,-2.057595496534775 50.73979886752439,-2.0453619362698046 50.74892539662549,-2.0348488778703295 50.758813029162525,-2.026222608546606 50.76930626235205,-2.0196200255571175 50.78023996203597,-2.015146424219851 50.791441944852124,-2.012873764584824 50.80273567797704,-2.012839448580592 50.81394305486918,-2.015045632376898 50.824887203781635,-2.019459090912274 50.83539528479962,-2.0260116430969055 50.84530123083424,-2.034601137228379 50.854448388409246,-2.045092986795196 50.86269201523514,-2.0573222372662254 50.86990159348424,-2.071096134877589 50.87596292035441,-2.0861971590574973 50.88077994091106,-2.102386471214103 50.88427629228161,-2.1194077243953173 50.88639653297961,-2.1369911710503118 50.887107036372456,-2.154858
        </gml:coordinates>
      </gml:Polygon>
    </ogc:Intersects>
</ogc:Filter>
```

I get the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ExceptionReport
 version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd"
>
    <Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="Unknown">
        <ExceptionText>
            <![CDATA[The geometry was not recognized.]]>
        
        </ExceptionText>
    </Exception>
    <Exception exceptionCode="OperationProcessingFailed" locator="Unknown">
        <ExceptionText>
            <![CDATA[Operator 'Intersects' can't parse geometry.]]>
        
        </ExceptionText>
    </Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

Am I doing something wrong with the XML structure here, or am I not able to query Zoomstack_Greenspace which intersects with a polygon?

Comment: looks like your using lat/lng where your srsName is in (OSGB 1936) Eastings and Northings - switch to srsName: 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326' should help

Comment: Good point - I've updated that but still see the same error message...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a case of bad formatting, and the API handling syntax errors by returning generic XML.

I missed the `>` off the `Polygon` definition, which resulted in this error being shown. Interestingly, using `posLine` rather than `coordinates` doesn't work at all, and results in an even less helpful XML response!